# count if and sum for mulltiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

this is my table example;

| Product | P.Price | Item | I.Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| prod1 | 10 | item1 | 5 |
| prod2 | 5 | item2 | 15 |

I want to calculate total price of selected products and items.

Example scenario;

price of 2x prod1, 1x prod2, 3x item1, 4x item2 is 70

Comment: 4x item2 70?? not 60?? Anyways, you can use formulas for this. Add a column to input quantity and just multiply and sum up.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I took item2 as 2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, something easy would be just adding quantities in another dataset and multiply and sum up. You may benefit from SUMPRODUCT function

[image]

First dataset is the one you posted as example
Second one is the same, but inputs are quantities

Formulas in column L are:

L2: `=SUMPRODUCT(G3:G4;B3:B4)`

L3: =`SUMPRODUCT(D3:D4;I3:I4)`

L4: `=SUM(L2:L3)`

For this to work both datasets must be exactly the same and same sorting.